# How do I locate all files that include specific word as part of name and end with specific extension?

Tags: command-line, locate

I am using `locate` command.

I want to find all files that end with specific extension and have specific keyword in their name.

For example I want to find image such as this:

> > myImageFromSummer.jpg

I want to search by keyword "Summer" and extension ".jpg".

How would command look like for this task?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
locate -b '*Summer*.jpg'
```

The `-b` option tells `locate` to only match the file name and `*` in the pattern match any number of characters.

Answer (score 1):

Use `*` in the name part an example would be :

```
sudo find /etc -name "*.jpg"
```

At least that works for me (I'm a complete newbe here but i know that will work).

```
sudo <--> to execute the command as root 

find  <--> the commando for searching

/etc  <--> is the directory where you want to find the archive

-name <--> option flag to detail what you are looking for 

*     <--> everything / anything

.jpg  <--> the extension
```

Now  the `*` can be used in the name part as in the extension part but don't do `*.*` because it will search for every single file containing a `.` you have in your search path.

Answer (score 0):

The following will search all mounted file systems:

```
sudo find / -name \*Summer*.jpg -print
```

If you wanted to search just below the current directory, replace the "/" with a ".".